# how to modify formData jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I want to submit a form with ajax. I get data of from using FormData like this:

```
var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
```

one of form's input is a color value in HSV format. I want to convert it to hex value. I have a jquery function to convert it, but I don't know how can I manipulate it's value in FormData.

another question is: How can I remove some fields (key, value) from FormData?

Comment: Please post the whole code, because your question is unclear there

Comment: my code is a simple ajax form submittion. I get data of from using FormData(). I want to manipulate values of inputs of form that is in FormData().

Comment: Maybe this will helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8244082/3452348

Comment: No. I need to extract values from Formdata, not append.

Comment: So,  $('form').serialize() ? ...

Comment: I can't access values of FormData() yet. but I can override values using append(key, value) . thanks Mr zlen

Comment: `append()` does not override, it appends. `set()` overrides.

Answer (score 5):

To get values by field name, use [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get)().

```
data.get('color');
```

If there are multiple values sharing the same field name, use [getAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll)().

```
data.getAll('colors');
```

To replace values by field name, use [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/set)().

```
data.set('color', '#abcdef');
```

It's important to note that `set()` replaces while `append()` appends when the field name exists. From the docs:

> The `set()` method of the `FormData` interface sets a new value for an existing key inside a `FormData` object, or adds the key/value if it does not already exist.
>
> The difference between `set()` and `FormData.append` is that if the specified key does already exist, `set()` will **overwrite** all existing values with the new one, whereas `FormData.append` will **append** the new value onto the end of the existing set of values.

To delete values by field name, use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/delete)().

```
data.delete('color');
```